# Why is the article count variable zero on all pages but the first, in this Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/pull/17/files)** in Laravel 8.

The **FrontendController** controller contains the data that is common to all the theme's views:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Settings;
use App\Models\ArticleCategory;
use App\Models\Page;
class FrontendController extends Controller
{
    protected $data;
    protected $site_settings;
    protected $theme_directory;
    protected $site_name;
    protected $tagline;
    protected $owner_name;
    protected $owner_email;
    protected $twitter;
    protected $facebook;
    protected $instagram;
    protected $is_cookieconsent;
    protected $is_infinitescroll;
    protected $pages;
    protected $article_categories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->site_settings = Settings::first();
        $this->theme_directory = $this->site_settings['theme_directory'] ?? null;
        $this->site_name = $this->site_settings['site_name'] ?? null;
        $this->tagline = $this->site_settings['tagline'] ?? null;
        $this->owner_name = $this->site_settings['owner_name'] ?? null;
        $this->owner_email = $this->site_settings['owner_email'] ?? null;
        $this->twitter = $this->site_settings['twitter'] ?? null;
        $this->facebook = $this->site_settings['facebook'] ?? null; 
        $this->instagram = $this->site_settings['instagram'] ?? null; 
        $this->is_cookieconsent = $this->site_settings['is_cookieconsent'] ?? null;
        $this->is_infinitescroll = $this->site_settings['is_infinitescroll'] ?? null;


        // Article categories
        $this->article_categories = ArticleCategory::all();

                // Pages
        $this->pages = Page::all();

        $this->data = [
          'theme_directory' => $this->theme_directory,
          'site_name' => $this->site_name,
          'tagline' => $this->tagline,
          'owner_name' => $this->owner_name,
          'owner_email' => $this->owner_email,
          'twitter' => $this->twitter,
          'facebook' => $this->facebook, 
          'instagram' => $this->instagram,
          'is_cookieconsent' => $this->is_cookieconsent,
          'is_infinitescroll' => $this->is_infinitescroll,
          'pages' => $this->pages,
          'categories' => $this->article_categories,
        ];
    }
}
```

The **ArticlesController** controller extends the one above:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\ArticleCategory;
use App\Models\Article;

class ArticlesController extends FrontendController {

    // Articles per page
    protected $per_page = 12;

    public function index(Request $request) {

        // Search query
        $qry = $request->input('search');

        $articlesQuery = Article::where('title', 'like', '%' . $qry . '%')
                                            ->orWhere('short_description', 'like', '%' . $qry . '%')
                                            ->orWhere('content', 'like', '%' . $qry . '%');

        $articles = $articlesQuery->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($this->per_page);

        // Search results count
        if ($request->input('search')) {
            $article_count = $articlesQuery->count();
        }       

        return view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/index', 
            array_merge($this->data, [
                'search_query' => $qry,
                'articles' => $articles,
                'article_count' => $article_count ?? null
            ])
        );
    }
    
}
```

The posts list view (index.blade.php):

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">

    @if (isset($search_query))
        <p class="mt-0 text-muted">We found {{ $article_count }} posts containing <span class="quote-inline">{{ $search_query }}</span>:</p>
    @endif

    @if (count($articles))
        @foreach ($articles as $article)
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a href="{{ url('/show/' . $article->slug) }}">
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        {{ $article->title }}
                    </h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        {{ $article->short_description }}
                    </h3>
                </a>
                <p class="post-meta">Posted by
                    <a href="{{ url('/author/' . $article->user->id) }}">{{ $article->user->first_name }} {{ $article->user->last_name }}</a>
                    on {{ date('j F, Y', strtotime($article->created_at)) }}
                </p>
            </div>

            @if(!$loop->last)<hr>@endif
            
        @endforeach
    @endif

    <!-- Pager -->
    @if($articles->hasPages())
        <div class="clearfix">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="next">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary {{ $articles->onFirstPage() ? 'disabled' : '' }}" href="{{ $articles->withQueryString()->previousPageUrl() }}">&larr; Newer Posts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="prev">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary {{ $articles->onLastPage() ? 'disabled' : '' }}" href="{{ $articles->withQueryString()->nextPageUrl() }}">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

#### The problem

Whenever there are paginated search results, the `$article_count` variable displays the total article count only on the first page. On all the others, **it shows 0**.

#### Questions

1. What causes this bug?
2. What is the easiest fix?

Comment: do you send "search" param in other pages?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using Laravel's paginator? It already contains the data you need

Comment: @brombeer I need a pager, not pagination. I have used the Laravel docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the search query above the articles variable. Like this way.

```
    // Search results count
if ($request->input('search')) {
    $article_count = $articlesQuery->count();
}
```

`$articles = $articlesQuery->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($this->per_page);`

Because every time it will paginate for page wise. If you paginate for the second page it may not contain any data. That's why you are getting the 0 value for the other page. Please use this way, I think the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

if you need total count of result in pagination, there is a variable exist named:**`"meta"`** inside it a variable **`"total"`** this is what you need.

pagination response like this:

```
{
  "products": {
  "data": [ YOUR DATA ],
  "links": { LINKS OF PAGES},
  "meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 11,
    "links": [ ALL LINKS OF ALL PAGES ],
    "path": "",
    "per_page": 20,
    "to": 20,
----> "total": 210  <---- THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED ----------
    }
  }
}
```

response image:
[image]

Comment: How does the above code fit into my code?

Comment: it is by default exist in pagination Laravel, see my answer again I'm add response image

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this earlier this month. It seems that once the the query is executed `->paginate($this->per_page)` or even `->get()` the objects are dumped in the query (perhaps memory management) which also means that the count also does not work as expected. What you can do is get the count prior to the query if you do not want to use laravel's pagination wrapper

```
$articlesQuery = Article::where('title', 'like', '%' . $qry . '%')
                                            ->orWhere('short_description', 'like', '%' . $qry . '%')
                                            ->orWhere('content', 'like', '%' . $qry . '%');

        // Search results count
        if ($request->input('search')) {
            $article_count = $articlesQuery->count();
        }    

        $articles = $articlesQuery->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($this->per_page);
```

I also found this to happen while having an offset which would mean that only not on the main page would the result be 0.

Luckily setting the count prior to the query will help.

Comment: What do you mean by "setting the count prior to the query" exactly? What I need is to *count the search results*.

Comment: see my answer : there is a variable exist named: `meta` inside it a variable `total` this is what you need. total of all result query. don't  need to this code.

Comment: See how I set "$article_count" prior to the actual paginate? That will be a count of the search results